# Michael Hartl's RoR tutorial - stuck on Chapter 9 - can't get RSpec tests to pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am an absolute beginner in programming (just started delving into Ruby on Rails) and this is my first post on StackOverflow, however I made a thorough research beforehand and none of the answers to similar problems provided me with a solution of my problem.

Namely, upon launching my test suite after chapter 9.2.1 of Michael Hartl's "Learn Web Development with Rails" tutorial, I receive 2 failures:

```
Failures:

1) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controller submitting to the update action 
 Failure/Error: before { patch user_path(user) }
 ActionController::ParameterMissing:
   param not found: user
 # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:39:in `user_params'
 # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:28:in `update'
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:63:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controller visiting the edit page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_title('Sign in') }
   expected #has_title?("Sign in") to return true, got false
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:59:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.35 seconds
70 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:64 # Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controller submitting to the update action 
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:59 # Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controller visiting the edit page
```

Here is the /spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:

```
describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

        describe "in the Users controller" do

            describe "visiting the edit page" do
                before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
                it { should have_title('Sign in') }
            end

            describe "submitting to the update action" do
                before { patch user_path(user) }
                specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
            end
        end
    end
end
```

And here is my /app/controllers/users_controller.rb:

```
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  ...

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  # Before filters

  def signed_in_user
    redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
  end

  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end
end
```

...and the signin page would be rendered here, I suppose:

/app/views/sessions/new.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>

    <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
</div>
</div>
```

In case any other file requires to be added here, please ask, as I am not sure if I posted everything needed. The first failure appears to have something to do with strong parameters within the User controller, although I reviewed the modified code bit by bit and found no discrepancies. In case of second failure, I have no idea what could go wrong there as the app seems to generate the right title when I access it in the browser, yet the test fails.

Thank you in advance for any effort put into helping me out.

Michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error is `ActionController::ParameterMissing`. That occurs because your `user_params` method calls `params.require(:user)`. That means that if params[:user] is not defined, it will raise an exception.

When you called `patch user_path(user)`, you did not pass in a user param, which caused the exception. Yet, you never should have gotten to `user_params`, because `signed_in_user` should have run before and redirected you to another page.

That leads me to speculate that your test user was already logged in. You may have put a `sign_in` call in an earlier part of `authentication_pages_spec.rb`. Have you? If so, move it inside of a `context "when signed in"` block and the spec should pass.

Likewise, if your test user is actually logged in, you would not see a sign in link -- so fixing that should fix your second error as well.

Comment: Thank You so much, Nick! I just needed to be pointed into right direction. Your guidelines were more than sufficient.